# Bootstrap date range picker custom event call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap date range picker https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker.
When i select date range & then i click on "apply button" it will call "apply.daterangepicker" and  return result.

```
#file.html
<div class="controls">
  <div class="input-prepend input-group">
    <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input type="text" style="width: 400px" name="daterange" id="daterange" class="form-control" value="" class="span4"/>
            &nbsp;
     <button id="stats" class="btn btn-small btn-sm btn-success">Show</button>
   </div>
 </div>


#file.js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#daterange').daterangepicker();
      $('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        console.log(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        console.log(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});
```

});

I would like to add my own custom event , i select date startDate & endDate, then i click "Show Button" instead of "Apply"  button , it should display result.

Please find below screen shot 
[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Post the solution here to help other people https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/517